# Parsing error: Unexpected token interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Migrating an app from react to use typescript. It's proving a little bit painful

I am getting this error in a `.tsx` file: `Parsing error: Unexpected token interface`

where I have

```
export interface IProps {
    propOne: any
    propTwo: any
}
```

any idea why it is doing this?

the interface lies just above my component

```
export interface IProps {
    propOne: any
    propTwo: any
}

export const mYComponent = (props: IProps) => {
   //component stuff
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

I've just removed eslint from my project and installed this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-eslint-rules and I'm using this in just the tslint.json file. not sure why it doesn't like the word interface? :/

Comment: It's possible that something about that export has a syntax error which only gets picked up at the word interface, what's above that export?

Comment: Is it possible you're not using typescript to compile the file, and just running it in plain node? It might explain it because `interface` is _not_ valid in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with version of prettier-standard if you use it. The versions 16.4.** have some issues yet.
I had the same problem, but after installing a bit lower version

```
yarn remove prettier-standard
yarn add -D prettier-standard@16.3.0
```

everything was fixed with interfaces error